# Does petite have a sexual connotation?

Tags: connotations

Is there a synonym that doesn't convey the sexual connotation? Also, could you list words that contain sexual connotations because I don't want to say them and get in trouble?

Comment: It would be impractical to provide a list.  And many words only have sexual connotations in certain situations or contexts or uses ("bed", "come", "bang", "big") and are such common and useful words that they can hardly be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

No it doesn't. It's just French for 'small'. In English it usually refers to someone's body size, usually feminine. But that's it.

Comment: I don't think the fact that it's French for small is relevant - sometimes things have different connotations (and sometimes different meanings entirely) in English from those they have in the languages they're borrowed from.  But I agree, it doesn't seem to have a sexual connotation. @Wisesequoia There's a list of example sentences that you can expand at https://www.lexico.com/definition/petite

Comment: Shops often have a petite range, usually for women under about 5'2". In everyday speech it tends to mean a woman with a small frame (so small across the shoulders, small feet etc) as well as not being very tall. Almost anything can have a sexual connotation if you say it with a waggle of the eyebrows, but petite is definitely an 'everyday' word.